# <header> tag bumping content down 60px only when < 980px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, web2py

When I reduce my browser window size to less than 980px in width, the content bumps down by 60px

What appears to be happening is that the `<header>` tag gets kicked down (I don't even know what that tag is doing there) below the `navbar`

I set the breadcrumbs to style of display:none, but including or excluding them doesn't seem to make a difference.

Not sure what to do to keep it consistent on different screen sizes

Example: http://www.wordisnear.org/

PS - I am using a web2py CMS called Pynuke, which may be using its own particular bootstrap layouts, but there is no S.O. tag for Pynuke (yet).

Comment: If you're not using the header tag, you should delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; do you know what the header tag is intended for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the viewport is wider than 980px, the navbar has `position: fixed` (via the `.navbar-fixed-top` class) -- notice when you scroll down, the navbar remains in position at the top of the screen. In that case, the 60px top margin of the `<header>` element actually overlaps with the navbar, so the header takes up no space in the main content section. Note, even though you are not using the header, its top margin is actually necessary here -- otherwise, your content would get bumped up and be obscured by the navbar (of course, you could get rid of the header and instead put a top margin on your content container directly).

When the screen size drops, there is a media query that changes the navbar to `position: static` (presumably so the navbar doesn't remain on screen during scrolling given that space is at a premium on smaller screens). In this case, the 60px top margin of the `<header>` element no longer overlaps with the navbar and instead takes up space at the top of the main content.

If you're not using the header or breadcrumbs, maybe just get rid of them. Then, add a 60px top margin to the main content div, and set a media query to remove that top margin when the width goes below 980px (so when the navbar switches from fixed to static, the margin will disappear).

Comment: Thanks! This makes total sense and I appreciate you taking the time to describe the situation as you have. If I could upvote twice I would. :)

Comment: PS - I don't even know what the header is supposed to be used for with this CMS/layout -- for now I will at least comment it out.

Comment: I ended up disabling the fixed header altogether for now, it wasn't necessary and eliminated the need for a media query.

Answer (score 3):

Use Media query for this, e.g. Example

```
@media all and (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 980px) {
body{
   margin-top:60px;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should be a viable solution, but I'm just not sure what is causing it to behave this way in the first place – i.e., why is it a problem only when smaller than 980px?